# Make hidden and visible versions of AvalonDock panels same size?

Tags: wpf, layout, avalondock

[image]

On this picture, the green and red highlighted panels are both set to the same size, and aren't hidden when I first launch the program. When I un-dock either of them though, the one I un-docked becomes as big as Red is right now when I hover over it. So my question is, how can I make AvalonDock keep the same size for a panel when it's docked and when it's un-docked?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer, but I'm just curious as to how you can see a control that is not visible... so, how do you do that?

Comment: lol, by hidden I mean not docked, i.e. you have to hover over the tabs on the edge of the window to see it. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoHideWidth and/or FloatingWidth in your LayoutAnchorable tag:

```
<avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Your Document Title"
                             AutoHideWidth="500"
                             FloatingWidth="500">
```

I used 500 pixels here, but you can set any width you like.

AutoHideWidth is the width when it pops out from its hidden state; FloatingWidth is the width when you drag it free from the side of the window.